# Switch updating from MySQL Master server to Slave server

Tags: c#, mysql

assuming that I have setup the Database (MySQL) Replication using Master-Slave configuration, and have synchronized those Master and Slave servers, how can my C# program know that it has to update the Slave server when the Master server fails? What are the conditions that the C# program switch from the Master server to the Slave server?

I am using MySQL server.